# drawing sloped rectangle upper edge shape as in yahoo digest news app using xml android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-shape

am trying to draw sloped rectangle upper edge shape and use it as linear layout background as in the picture:

here is the link to the design am trying to achieve: http://postimg.org/image/krjwfcisz/

I tried to draw a rectangular and rotate it but it didn't work fine.

so how to create that shape.

sorry about grammar mistakes, am not fluent :P.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well I think it's a silly thing to answer to my question but am doing so because it may help other people.

I couldn't manage to create what I need using XML.

so here is how to create a sloped rectangular using onDraw method.

First you need to create a class that extends `View` class then

```
public class SharpRectView extends View {
public SharpRectView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SharpRectView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SharpRectView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    float width = getWidth();
    float height = getHeight();
    Path path = new Path();
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_white));
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    path.moveTo(0,0);
    path.lineTo(width, 0.26f * width);
    path.lineTo(width, height);
    path.lineTo(0, height);
    path.lineTo(0, 0);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
}
}
```

then you can use this view class in your layout as a customized view as follows:

```
<com.example.SharpRectView
            android:id="@+id/sharp_rect"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-120dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />
```

and to give credits to the guy that I used his project to find the solution please visit: https://github.com/qianlvable/ParallaxEffectDemo
his username is: qianlv